# Remove settings

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'm making an iOS App, and I want to remove the Settings option when you tap the bottom bar (so only close and exit will remain). Is there any way to do this, and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "(so only close and exit will remain)" Please elaborate it.

Comment: You need to provide some info here. Which bottom bar? Where is close and exit? Which part of the app are you in? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Take a look at this page [link](http://imgur.com/a/8Z4Yr), on the last image you'll see a screenshot with a bar at the bottom saying 59 km/h if you tap that bar the image above will pop-up, when you press "Instellingen" the next screen will pop-up. I want that "Instellingen" button to be removed so people can't access the settings.

Comment: You should remove the "Instellingen" option from your UIActionsheet (I believe you have used ActionSheet for options). If not, than kindly explain in detail what you want and which code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the required changes are to be made inside SKTNavigationManager.m:

1. you need to remove the "settings" option from the action sheet

Before:

```
- (void)mapView:(SKMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
SKTActionSheet *sheet = nil;
if ([self currentNavigationState] == SKTNavigationStateCalculatingRoute) {
    sheet = [SKTActionSheet actionSheetWithButtonTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(kSKTQuitKey, nil)] cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(kSKTCancelKey, nil)];
} else {
    sheet = [SKTActionSheet actionSheetWithButtonTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(kSKTSettingsKey, nil), NSLocalizedString(kSKTQuitKey, nil)] cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(kSKTCancelKey, nil)];
}

sheet.delegate = self;
_activeActionSheet = sheet;
[sheet showInView:_mainView];
}
```

After:

```
- (void)mapView:(SKMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
SKTActionSheet *sheet = nil;
if ([self currentNavigationState] == SKTNavigationStateCalculatingRoute) {
    sheet = [SKTActionSheet actionSheetWithButtonTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(kSKTQuitKey, nil)] cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(kSKTCancelKey, nil)];
} else {
    sheet = [SKTActionSheet actionSheetWithButtonTitles:@[ NSLocalizedString(kSKTQuitKey, nil)] cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(kSKTCancelKey, nil)];
}

sheet.delegate = self;
_activeActionSheet = sheet;
[sheet showInView:_mainView];
}
```

2. change the action handler for the selected buttons (reflecting the new menu structure).

Before:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(SKTActionSheet *)actionSheet didSelectButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (index == 0) {
    if ([self currentNavigationState] == SKTNavigationStateCalculatingRoute) {
        [self stopNavigationWithReason:SKTNavigationStopReasonUserQuit stopAudio:YES];
    } else {
        //remove states that should't exist while settings view is visible
        [self removeState:SKTNavigationStateBlockRoads];
        [self removeState:SKTNavigationStateOverview];
        [self removeState:SKTNavigationStateRouteInfo];

        [self pushNavigationStateIfNotPresent:SKTNavigationStateSettings];
    }

    [actionSheet dismissInstantly];
    self.mainView.settingsView.delegate = self;
} else if (index == 1) {
    if (self.isFreeDrive) {
        [self stopNavigationWithReason:SKTNavigationStopReasonUserQuit stopAudio:YES];
    } else {
        [self confirmStopNavigation];
    }

    [actionSheet dismiss];
}

_activeActionSheet = nil;
}
```

After:

```
(void)actionSheet:(SKTActionSheet *)actionSheet didSelectButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (index == 0) {
    if (self.isFreeDrive) {
        [self stopNavigationWithReason:SKTNavigationStopReasonUserQuit stopAudio:YES];
    } else {
        [self confirmStopNavigation];
    }

    [actionSheet dismiss];
}

_activeActionSheet = nil;
}
```